# i want to know the rule of using indefinite articles and when you don’t have to use them

Tags: grammar

I am writing an essay on economics. I said something like, there are four economic systems, the first one is traditional economy.
should i say, the first one is (a)traditional economy or it is just fine the way I said it?

Answer (score 1):

"The rule" is that singular countable content nouns that don't have another determiner get the article "a" or "an".

But applying this rule in practice means deciding when something is a noun (and not a participle etc) when it is countable and singular (tricky since one of the main ways to decide if it is countable is to check if it has singular article). And it is tricky to decide if another determiner should have been used instead.

In your particular example, the problem is using the word "economy" — Is this meant to be countable or not? — tricky because it could be either.   If you realise that you are listing *systems* and not *economies*, you will find it much easier to phase this. You have got into difficulties because the first one isn't "traditional economy", but "traditional economic system". You will understand that these are particular determined systems, so should have "The" as their determiner.

> There are four economic systems. The first one is the traditional economic system.